# Validate whole input with a regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to build a regex-based validation for my forms.

E.g. an IMEI has always 15 numbers, so the regex for this input-type is [0-9]{15}.
BUT if the user types-in something like "m154876598562354" or just more then 15 numbers the Javascript RegEx(...).test() still says true for the correctly found 15 numbers, but in the end the input itself is wrong.

Am I missing something about the regex-concept?

I wanted to use regex because of its flexibility. I can't just test the values static because the inputs and values to test are generated dynamically for the user. Therefore I don't know what input will be checked at design-time.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you want to check you match the whole string.

Use anchors : `/^[0-9]{15}$/`